# Fastest Way to Upload Multiple Image to Server in android

Tags: android, server

I've multiple images to upload in server and i've a method for upload single image to server. now I'm using this method to send multiple images by creating loop for each images.

Is there any fastest way to send multiple images to server?. Thanks in advance...

```
public int imageUpload(GroupInfoDO infoDO) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        int groupId = 0;
        try {
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(infoDO.getDpUrl());
            String fileName = infoDO.getDpUrl().substring(
                    infoDO.getDpUrl().lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
                    infoDO.getDpUrl().length());
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                    "http://192.168.1.24:8081/REST/groupreg/upload");
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data,
                    "application/octet-stream");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("uploadFile", bab);
            reqEntity.addPart("name", new StringBody(fileName));
            reqEntity.addPart("grpId", new StringBody(infoDO.getGlobalAppId()
                    + ""));
            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                String json = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                Map<String, Object> mapObject = mapper.readValue(json,
                        new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                        });
                if ((mapObject != null)
                        && (mapObject.get("status").toString()
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS"))) {
                    groupId = (Integer.valueOf(mapObject.get("groupId")
                            .toString()));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e1.toString());
        }
        return groupId;
    }
```

Comment: It depends also from your server by the way.. In this way how much time spends to do the upload? Is it working right now?

Comment: Thank you for  your reply. It takes min 10 sec for single images to get response from server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many methods to upload more images to the server.. one could be including two libraries: apache-mime4j-0.6.jar and httpmime-4.0.1.jar.. After that create your java main code:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FileUploadTest extends Activity {

    private static final int SELECT_FILE1 = 1;
    private static final int SELECT_FILE2 = 2;
    String selectedPath1 = "NONE";
    String selectedPath2 = "NONE";
    TextView tv, res;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Button b1,b2,b3;
    HttpEntity resEntity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        res = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.res);
        tv.setText(tv.getText() + selectedPath1 + "," + selectedPath2);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upload);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery(SELECT_FILE1);
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openGallery(SELECT_FILE2);
            }
        });
        b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!(selectedPath1.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("NONE")) && !(selectedPath2.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("NONE"))){
                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(FileUploadTest.this, "", "Uploading files to server.....", false);
                     Thread thread=new Thread(new Runnable(){
                            public void run(){
                                doFileUpload();
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                    public void run() {
                                        if(progressDialog.isShowing())
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                    });
                    thread.start();
                }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please select two files to upload.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void openGallery(int req_code){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select file to upload "), req_code);
   }

   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE1)
            {
                selectedPath1 = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("selectedPath1 : " + selectedPath1);
            }
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE2)
            {
                selectedPath2 = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("selectedPath2 : " + selectedPath2);
            }
            tv.setText("Selected File paths : " + selectedPath1 + "," + selectedPath2);
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    private void doFileUpload(){

        File file1 = new File(selectedPath1);
        File file2 = new File(selectedPath2);
        String urlString = "http://10.0.2.2/upload_test/upload_media_test.php";
        try
        {
             HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
             FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1);
             FileBody bin2 = new FileBody(file2);
             MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
             reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile1", bin1);
             reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile2", bin2);
             reqEntity.addPart("user", new StringBody("User"));
             post.setEntity(reqEntity);
             HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
             resEntity = response.getEntity();
             final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
             if (resEntity != null) {
                 Log.i("RESPONSE",response_str);
                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run() {
                             try {
                                res.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                                res.setText("n Response from server : n " + response_str);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Upload Complete. Check the server uploads directory.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                           }
                    });
             }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
             Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
      }
}
```

Now your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Multiple File Upload from CoderzHeaven"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get First File">
</Button>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get Second File">
</Button>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/upload"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start Upload">
</Button>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Selected File path : "
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/res"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text=""
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

of course, include the internet permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And voilà. Anyway i followed this example in my case: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/16/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-one-request-along-with-other-string-parameters-in-android/ try to see there.. There are 4 methods to upload multiple files. See which you like

Comment: I like HttpEntity too, however, it's deprecated now.

Comment: how I can add those library??
please help

Comment: @Md.AshikurRahman From the `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 2):

Using Volley

```
private void uploadMultipleImage(){

    dialog = ogressDialog.show(WhatsappUpload.this,"","Loading...",false);
    String str[] = new String[MainActivity.bitmaps.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<MainActivity.bitmaps.size();i++){
        str[i] =  getStringImage(MainActivity.bitmaps.get(i));
    }
    imgs = TextUtils.join(",",str);
  //  Log.d("Sid","Join : " + TextUtils.join(",",str));

    String urlImages = "http://192.168.100.13/iupload/test_image.php";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlImages,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    dialog.hide();
                    Log.d("Sid","Response : " + response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),object.getString("msg"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d("Sid","JSON Exception : " + e);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            dialog.hide();
            Log.d("Sid","Volly Error : " + error);
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            String cap  = !TextUtils.isEmpty(edtCaption.getText().toString()) ? edtCaption.getText().toString() : "Default Captions!";
            Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            params.put("captions",cap);
            params.put("images", imgs);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}


public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. This is useful for one or two or three image uploading, and Use [httpmime-4.2.1.jar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h30kh2r2j6lhgaw/httpmime-4.2.1.jar?dl=0)

**Activity**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;


public class MultiImageActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CAMERA_PICTURE = 1;
    private static final int GALLERY_PICTURE = 2;
    String filePath1 = null;
    String filePath2 = null;
    String filePath3 = null;
    Bitmap chosenImage;
    File destination = null;
    ImageView ivImg1, ivImg2, ivImg3;

    String img1Selected1 = null, img2Selected1 = null, img3Selected1 = null;
    String img1Selected2 = null, img2Selected2 = null, img3Selected2 = null;

    LinearLayout llImgHolder;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_multi_image);

        Button btnImg1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_multi_img_1);
        Button btnImg2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_multi_img_2);
        Button btnImg3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_multi_img_3);
        Button btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_multi_upload);

        llImgHolder = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_multi_img_holder);

        ivImg1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_multi_img1);
        ivImg2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_multi_img2);
        ivImg3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_multi_img3);

        btnImg1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                img1Selected1 = "fulfilled";
                choosePictureAction();
            }
        });

        btnImg2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (img1Selected2 != null) {
                    img2Selected1 = "fulfilled";
                    choosePictureAction();
                }else {
                    Log.e("Please select first image", "Please select first image");
                }
            }
        });

        btnImg3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                if (img2Selected2 != null) {
                    img3Selected1 = "fulfilled";
                    choosePictureAction();
                }else {
                    Log.e("Please select second image", "Please select second image");
                }
            }
        });

        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String url="______________your_api________";

                new uploadAsynTask().execute(url);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            chosenImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            chosenImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
            destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            FileOutputStream fo;
            //filePath1 = destination.toString();

            if(img1Selected1 != null){

                filePath1 = destination.toString();
            }else if(img2Selected1 != null){

                filePath2 = destination.toString();
            }else if(img3Selected1 != null){

                filePath3 = destination.toString();
            }

            try {
                destination.createNewFile();
                fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(chosenImage != null){
                if(img1Selected1 != null){
                    llImgHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ivImg1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    img1Selected1 = null;
                    img1Selected2 = "fulfilled";
                    ivImg1.setImageBitmap(chosenImage);
                }else if(img2Selected1 != null){
                    ivImg2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    img2Selected1 = null;
                    img2Selected2 = "fulfilled";
                    ivImg2.setImageBitmap(chosenImage);
                }else if(img3Selected1 != null){
                    ivImg3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    img3Selected1 = null;
                    img3Selected2 = "fulfilled";
                    ivImg3.setImageBitmap(chosenImage);
                }

            }


        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_PICTURE
                && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        } else if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICTURE
                && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
            destination = new File(selectedImagePath);

            if(img1Selected1 != null){
                filePath1 = selectedImagePath;
            }else if(img2Selected1 != null){
                filePath2 = selectedImagePath;
            }else if(img3Selected1 != null){
                filePath3 = selectedImagePath;
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
            int scale = 1;
            while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                    && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;
            options.inSampleSize = scale;
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            chosenImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);

            if(chosenImage!=null){

                if(img1Selected1 != null){
                    llImgHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ivImg1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    img1Selected1 = null;
                    img1Selected2 = "fulfilled";
                    ivImg1.setImageBitmap(chosenImage);
                }else if(img2Selected1 != null){
                    ivImg2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    img2Selected1 = null;
                    img2Selected2 = "fulfilled";
                    ivImg2.setImageBitmap(chosenImage);
                }else if(img3Selected1 != null){
                    ivImg3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    img3Selected1 = null;
                    img3Selected2 = "fulfilled";
                    ivImg3.setImageBitmap(chosenImage);
                }

            }

        } else if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICTURE
                && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        }
    }

    private void choosePictureAction(){

        final CharSequence[] items = {"Camera", "Gallery", "Cancel"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MultiImageActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                if(items[which].equals("Camera")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PICTURE);
                }else if(items[which].equals("Gallery")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_PICTURE);
                }else if(items[which].equals("Cancel")){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            }
        });

        builder.show();

    }


    private class uploadAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MultiImageActivity.this, null, null);
            ProgressBar spinner = new android.widget.ProgressBar(MultiImageActivity.this, null,android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);
            spinner.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#009689"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.setContentView(spinner);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            Log.e("FilePathBin1", filePath1);

            File file1 = new File(filePath1);
            File file2 = null;
            File file3 = null;

            if(img2Selected2 != null){
                Log.e("FilePathBin2", filePath2);
                file2 = new File(filePath2);
            }
            if(img3Selected2 != null){
                Log.e("FilePathBin3", filePath3);
                file3 = new File(filePath3);
            }

            MultipartEntity reqEntity;
            HttpEntity resEntity;
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String postURL = params[0];
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);

                FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1);
                FileBody bin2 = null;
                FileBody bin3 = null;

                if(img2Selected2 != null){

                    bin2 = new FileBody(file2);
                }
                if(img3Selected2 != null){

                    bin3 = new FileBody(file3);
                }

                reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);



                reqEntity.addPart("parking_title", new StringBody("Test13:26"));
                reqEntity.addPart("latitude", new StringBody("10.12313213"));
                reqEntity.addPart("longtitude", new StringBody("12.123213213"));
                reqEntity.addPart("note", new StringBody("12"));

                reqEntity.addPart("filename[0]", bin1);

                if(img2Selected2 != null){
                    img2Selected2 = null;
                    reqEntity.addPart("filename[1]", bin2);
                }
                if(img3Selected2 != null){
                    img3Selected2 = null;
                    reqEntity.addPart("filename[2]", bin3);
                }
                reqEntity.addPart("spot_types[0]", new StringBody("1"));
                reqEntity.addPart("spot_types[1]", new StringBody("2"));
                reqEntity.addPart("spot_types[2]", new StringBody("3"));
                reqEntity.addPart("spot_properties[0]", new StringBody("1"));
                reqEntity.addPart("spot_properties[1]", new StringBody("2"));
                reqEntity.addPart("spot_properties[2]", new StringBody("3"));

                post.setEntity(reqEntity);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                resEntity = response.getEntity();
                String entityContentAsString = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                Log.d("stream:", entityContentAsString);



                return entityContentAsString;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            if(result != null){
                dialog.dismiss();
                Log.e("addPhotoResult", result);

                filePath1 = null;
                filePath2 = null;
                filePath3 = null;

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                    String error = jsonObject.getString("Error");
                    String message = jsonObject.getString("message");

                    Log.e("error", error);
                    Log.e("message", message);



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }



        }

    }

}
```

**Xml Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    tools:context="com.app.multiimage.MultiImageActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_multi_img_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="@string/multi_img1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_multi_img_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_multi_img_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="@string/multi_img2"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_multi_img_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_multi_img_2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="@string/multi_img3"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_multi_img_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_multi_img_3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_multi_img1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_multi_img2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_multi_img1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_multi_img3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_multi_img2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_multi_upload"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_multi_img_holder"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="@string/multi_upload"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```